# VirtualBox Headless Frontend process wont stop even after Vagrant halt/reload command

Tags: windows, vagrant, virtualbox

The processes running previously from Vagrant up are not stopped/killed after running Vagrant halt/reload which in turn gives me this error.

```
Command: ["startvm", "c76a8bec-7a40-47c9-b01f-1c8b2b0a7def", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: The VM session was closed before any attempt to power it on VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component SessionMachine, interface ISession
```

I'm pretty sure it's because of the processes running because when I kill the process via task manager and rerun the commands it works properly. What seems to be causing the processes to not be removed? or does Vagrant halt/reload actually not stop them?

Using Windows 10 with Virtualbox 6.1 and Vagrant 2.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen this behavior on two different Windows 10 machines. It happens even without using Vagrant; sometimes the headless VM process simply doesn't exit. I've never seen it before VirtualBox 6.1, and I suspect it's simply a bug in VirtualBox.

Comment: Yeah, it seems there is a bug on the newer versions according to https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/12484 . Just downgraded my VirtualBox and it's working.